# Detection of USB port and serial port from 64-bit Ubuntu to 32-bit guest Ubuntu in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, virtualbox-networking

I am using TinyOS tool in a 32-bit Ubuntu install in VirtualBox. My host machine is 64-bit Ubuntu.

Now I have successfully compiled the code and want to deploy it on IRIS mote. But my Ubuntu OS in virtual machine is not detecting the USB or serial ports.
I have tried some settings in serial port tab of VirtualBox (COM1 on port# and /dev/ttyS0 in device path) but nothing works.

How can I make it detect the pendrive and my IRIS sensor mote?

Comment: Add yourself to the `vboxusers` group with `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER`!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access the `USB` ports in the virtualbox machine then you have to belong to the `vboxusers` group so add yourself with:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER
```

Then restart your system and try again.